# Quais possíveis problemas podem surgir ao configurar o Python como variável de ambiente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, variáveis-de-ambiente

Ao instalar o Python, o fiz em conjunto ao Anaconda e não marquei a caixinha de adicionar às variáveis de ambiente porque havia um aviso de que poderia ocasionar em problemas futuros. Quais problemas podem surgir ao adicionar o Python/Anaconda ao path?

Answer (score -2):

Sem adicionar o Python/Anaconda ao path, você não será capaz de executar o Python de forma global no seu sistema, ou seja, você terá que especificar o caminho para o Python/Anaconda em todos os lugares onde deseja usá-lo. Isso pode ser um problema se você precisar usar o Python em vários lugares diferentes ou se quiser que outras pessoas usem seu código Python.